# Why my javascript code not working for the dashboard of wordpress admin?

Tags: javascript

I am created a dashboard widgets using wp_add_dashboard_widgets() in admin area and created there a button ,i want when i click on button my script to be worked while that not working ,
all code of dashboard widgets putted in functions.php file and also written the script in functions.php file ,
what have you any solution where i can put the javascript by which my click events can work?please guide me.

this is my javascript code inside functions.php file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('.dash_appoint_r').on('click', function(){
    alert('hello');
    }); 



</script>
```

and this is my php code where a button avilable as i told you.

```
<?php
    foreach($result as $all_records)

    {
                    // if($all_records->appointment_status==pending)
                    // {
                        // $pending=$all_records->appointment_status;
                    // }
                    // else
                    // {
                        // $pending='pending';
                    // }
        ?>

                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $all_records->id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $all_records->patient_name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $all_records->patient_email; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $all_records->patient_phone; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $all_records->appointment_date; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $all_records->appointment_doctors; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $all_records->appointment_status;?></td>
                    <td>
                    <select id="ack_status">
                    <option value="pending">pending</option>
                    <option value="success">success</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><button type="button" >submit</button></td>
                  </tr>
        <?php

    }
    ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

please,can you please tell me what i am doing wrong and where i need to put the javscript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your script into your `functions.php`

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-great-script', get_site_url() . '/js/my-great-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

Then, in your file (`my-great-script.js`), you will have to have something like this:

```
jQuery('.dash_appoint_r').on('click', function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: loading is working ,but click event is not working why please guide me?

Comment: i checked after putting only alert('hello') in my-great-script.js then it working while this code is putting jQuery('.dash_appoint_r').on('click', function(){
    alert('hello');
}); into the my-great-script.js then not working,what can be problem ?

Comment: to check the problem, use the full code, click the button and check the browser console to see what is happening.

Comment: getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at my-great-script.js:2"  but i don't know how to resolved it ?can you please help me?